# Tooltip alignement with Chart.js v2

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm having trouble aligning the tooltip text on a doughnut chart.
It keeps getting stuck to the bottom of the tooltip like that:

[image: doughnut chart with non-aligned tooltip]

I would like to make it aligned vertically.

Here are the default options I used

```
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '\'Titillium Web\', \'Helvetica\', \'Arial\', \'sans-serif\'';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'bold';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.backgroundColor = '#181818';
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodySpacing = 30;
```

And the code I used to generate the chart:

```
function PercentageTooltip(tooltipItem, data) {
    let index = tooltipItem.index;

    return data.labels[index] + ' : ' + data.datasets[0].data[index].toFixed(0) + '%';
}

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['Homme', 'Femme', 'Inconnu'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [sexs.male, sexs.female, sexs.unknown],
            backgroundColor: ['#87c2d6', '#f86e7a', '#dddddd'],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#b7ced6', '#f89099', '#eeeeee']
        }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: PercentageTooltip
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And finally I've tried to play with the global options `Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.{bodySpacing,xPadding}` but I can't get the expected result.

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Tektiv,

I've updated your answer as it didn't solve my issue on chromium 54 as you can see here:

[image: dougnut with wrong alignement]

I'm using this option:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.footerFontSize = 0;
```

Along with this footer callback:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            footer: function() { return ' '; },
            label: PercentageTooltip
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bkv12ga/), and the result is correct for me (although this is very hacky) :

[image: dougnut with correct tooltip alignement]

Cheers!